# Cannot read field "timeProcess" because "this.parquetReaderStats" is null

Tags: parquet, apache-drill

I'm using [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/) to open a parquet file.

After `drill-embedded`, following the [official documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-parquet-files/) I run:

```
apache drill> SELECT * FROM `dfs`.`/path/to/my/file.parquet`;
```

But I get the following error in return:

```
Error: INTERNAL_ERROR ERROR: Cannot read field "timeProcess" because "this.parquetReaderStats" is null

Fragment: 0:0

Please, refer to logs for more information.

[Error Id: a5b9bc2e-1c9b-4ef3-94d7-f245aa1a55db on MYUSERNAME:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

That error is a secondary one that doesn't reveal the underlying problem. If you come to the Drill Slack channel or user mailing list it will be possible to investigate fuether. Important information to bring you with is the version of Drill and the JSON profile of a failed query (accessible from the Profiles tab of the Drill web UI which will be at http://localhost:8047 since you're running embedded Drill).